# Error installing FeedZirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, feedparser, feedzirra

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am excited about Feed parsing but when I install FeedZirra I am getting this error.

I use Windows 7 and Ruby 1.8.7.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
C:\Ruby187>gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
http://gems.github.com added to sources

C:\Ruby187>gem install pauldix-feedzirra
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pauldix-feedzirra:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby187/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include
        --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib
        --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
extconf.rb:12:   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taf2-curb-0
.5.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taf2-curb-0.5.4.0/ext/gem_ma
ke.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install libcurl for the `curb` gem, which your app depends on somewhere. You can get it [here](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=lib&os=Win32), but you're on your own as far as installation goes. I'm not a windows user, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I tried downloading curl from the link x1a4 had mentioned. It doesn't work with ruby 1.9.2, even with dev toolkit installed:

```
C:\>gem install feedzirra -- --with-curl-lib=c:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\lib --with-curl-include=C:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing feedzirra:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-curl-lib=c:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\lib --with-curl-include=C:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... yes
checking for curl/curl.h... yes
checking for curlinfo_redirect_time... yes
checking for curlinfo_response_code... yes
checking for curlinfo_filetime... yes
checking for curlinfo_redirect_count... yes
checking for curlinfo_os_errno... yes
checking for curlinfo_num_connects... yes
checking for curlinfo_ftp_entry_path... yes
checking for curl_version_ssl... yes
checking for curl_version_libz... yes
checking for curl_version_ntlm... yes
checking for curl_version_gssnegotiate... yes
checking for curl_version_debug... yes
checking for curl_version_asynchdns... yes
checking for curl_version_spnego... yes
checking for curl_version_largefile... yes
checking for curl_version_idn... yes
checking for curl_version_sspi... yes
checking for curl_version_conv... yes
checking for curlproxy_http... yes
checking for curlproxy_socks4... yes
checking for curlproxy_socks5... yes
checking for curlauth_basic... yes
checking for curlauth_digest... yes
checking for curlauth_gssnegotiate... yes
checking for curlauth_ntlm... yes
checking for curlauth_anysafe... yes
checking for curlauth_any... yes
checking for curle_tftp_notfound... yes
checking for curle_tftp_perm... yes
checking for curle_tftp_diskfull... yes
checking for curle_tftp_illegal... yes
checking for curle_tftp_unknownid... yes
checking for curle_tftp_exists... yes
checking for curle_tftp_nosuchuser... yes
checking for curle_send_fail_rewind... yes
checking for curle_ssl_engine_initfailed... yes
checking for curle_login_denied... yes
checking for curlmopt_maxconnects... yes
checking for curle_conv_failed... yes
checking for curle_conv_reqd... yes
checking for curle_ssl_cacert_badfile... yes
checking for curle_remote_file_not_found... yes
checking for curle_ssh... yes
checking for curle_ssl_shutdown_failed... yes
checking for curle_again... yes
checking for curle_ssl_crl_badfile... yes
checking for curle_ssl_issuer_error... yes
checking for curlopt_username... yes
checking for curlopt_password... yes
checking for curlinfo_primary_ip... yes
checking for curlauth_digest_ie... yes
checking for curlftpmethod_multicwd... yes
checking for curlftpmethod_nocwd... yes
checking for curlftpmethod_singlecwd... yes
checking for curlm_bad_socket... yes
checking for curlm_unknown_option... yes
checking for curl_multi_timeout()... no
checking for curl_multi_fdset()... no
checking for curl_multi_perform()... no
checking for Ruby 1.9 Hash... yes
checking for Ruby 1.9 st.h... yes
checking for curl_easy_escape... yes
creating curb_config.h
creating Makefile

make
C:/Ruby192/bin/ruby -e "puts 'EXPORTS', 'Init_curb_core'"  > curb_core-i386-mingw32.def
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_
H=\"curb_config.h\" -IC:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -W
no-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall  -o curb.o -c curb.c
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_
H=\"curb_config.h\" -IC:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -W
no-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall  -o curb_easy.o -c curb_easy.c
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_
H=\"curb_config.h\" -IC:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -W
no-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall  -o curb_errors.o -c curb_errors.c
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_
H=\"curb_config.h\" -IC:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -W
no-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall  -o curb_multi.o -c curb_multi.c
curb_multi.c: In function 'create_crt_fd':
curb_multi.c:409:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
curb_multi.c:412:9: warning: unused variable 'r'
curb_multi.c: In function 'cleanup_crt_fd':
curb_multi.c:424:17: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_
H=\"curb_config.h\" -IC:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -W
no-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall  -o curb_postfield.o -c curb_postfield.c
gcc -I. -IC:/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/i386-mingw32 -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/C/Ruby192/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_
H=\"curb_config.h\" -IC:\curl-7.21.3-devel-mingw32\include    -O3 -g -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -W
no-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long -Wall  -o curb_upload.o -c curb_upload.c
gcc -shared -s -o curb_core.so curb.o curb_easy.o curb_errors.o curb_multi.o curb_postfield.o curb_upload.o -L. -LC:/Ruby192/lib -Lc:\curl-7.21.3-deve
l-mingw32\lib -L.  -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base,--enable-auto-import curb_core-i386-mingw32.def  -lmsvcrt-ruby191 -lcurl  -lshell32 -lws2_32
curb.o: In function `ruby_curl_conv_q':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:214: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_version_info'
curb.o: In function `ruby_curl_sspi_q':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:198: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_version_info'
curb.o: In function `ruby_curl_idn_q':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:179: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_version_info'
curb.o: In function `ruby_curl_largefile_q':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:162: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_version_info'
curb.o: In function `ruby_curl_spnego_q':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:146: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_version_info'
curb.o:C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:129: more undefined references to `_imp__curl_version_info' follow
curb.o: In function `Init_curb_core':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:226: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:227: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_version_info'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb.c:232: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_version'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_clone':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:268: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_duphandle'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_unescape':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:3171: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_unescape'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:3178: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_free'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_set_nosignal':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2456: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_set_version':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2441: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_set_delete_option':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2476: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2473: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_set_head_option':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2421: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o:C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2418: more undefined references to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt' follow
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_reset':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:329: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_reset'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:333: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:340: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_ftp_entry_path_get':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:3085: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_num_connects_get':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:3044: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_os_errno_get':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:3015: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_content_type_get':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2972: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_ssl_verify_result_get':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2915: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
curb_easy.o:C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2898: more undefined references to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo' follow
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_head':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2397: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_get':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2224: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_new':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:226: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:241: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `cb_each_ftp_command':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:1846: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_append'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_free':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:146: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:150: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:154: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:146: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:150: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:154: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_close':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:292: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:302: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_get':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2224: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_head':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2397: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_verb_str':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2241: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2241: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_escape':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:3143: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_escape'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:3149: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_free'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_verb_str':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2241: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `cb_each_http_header':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:1837: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_append'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_put_data_set':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:818: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_put':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2497: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2497: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_post_body_set':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:774: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_perform_post':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2334: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2353: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formfree'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_setup':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:1873: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2124: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_append'
curb_easy.o: In function `ruby_curl_easy_cleanup':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2158: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2164: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_easy.c:2171: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_setopt'
curb_errors.o: In function `rb_curl_easy_error':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_errors.c:442: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_strerror'
curb_errors.o: In function `rb_curl_multi_error':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_errors.c:492: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_strerror'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_errors.c:492: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_strerror'
curb_multi.o: In function `ruby_curl_multi_max_connects':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:188: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_setopt'
curb_multi.o: In function `ruby_curl_multi_new':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:91: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_init'
curb_multi.o: In function `curl_multi_free':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:76: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_cleanup'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_mutli_handle_complete':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:332: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_getinfo'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_multi_remove':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:286: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_remove_handle'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_mutli_handle_complete':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:342: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_slist_free_all'
curb_multi.o: In function `ruby_curl_multi_add':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:235: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_add_handle'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:248: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_perform'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_multi_remove':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:286: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_remove_handle'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:286: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_remove_handle'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_multi_run':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:395: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_perform'
curb_multi.o: In function `ruby_curl_multi_perform':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:509: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_fdset'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:533: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_info_read'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_multi_run':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:395: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_perform'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_multi_read_info':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:379: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_info_read'
curb_multi.o: In function `rb_curl_multi_run':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_multi.c:395: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_multi_perform'
curb_postfield.o: In function `ruby_curl_postfield_to_str':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_postfield.c:447: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_escape'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_postfield.c:454: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_free'
curb_postfield.o: In function `append_to_form':
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_postfield.c:76: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formadd'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_postfield.c:115: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formadd'
C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\curb-0.7.10\ext/curb_postfield.c:120: undefined reference to `_imp__curl_formadd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [curb_core.so] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this bug on Ubuntu 12.0. The following may help.

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-dbg libcurl3-gnutls libcurl3-nss

gem install feedzirra
```

worked!!

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu I had to run

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev
```

Then ran the gem install again and it completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libcurl not for `curb` gem, but for `taf2-curb` gem , just looking carefull in error log. You can find my answer about installation on taf2-curb.