# Problem installing gem pauldix-feedzirra on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

**I am trying to install pauldix-feedzirra gem on windows xp and getting error like this :**

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pauldix-feedzirra:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in curl.lib... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include
        --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib
        --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
extconf.rb:12:   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.

Gem files will remain installed in C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taf2-curb-0.5.4.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/InstantRails-2.0-win/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taf2-curb-0.5.4.0/ext/gem_make.out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing FeedZirra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919145/error-installing-feedzirra)

Answer (score 0):

Execute Below command and its works

gem install pauldix-feedzirra --platform=mswin32