# Problem installing LibCurl + LibXML + FeedZirra on Windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, libcurl, feedparser, libxml-ruby

I am rails newbie. I am working on Windows XP.

I have this version of ruby.

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i386-mingw32]
```

I have Rails 2.3.8 installed.

I am trying to install feedzirra trying every possible way after watching the Rails Cast 168.

First I tried to install using gem install pauldix-feedzirra. I got this error.

```
    C:\Ruby>gem install pauldix-feedzirra
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing pauldix-feedzirra:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for curl-config... no
    checking for main() in -lcurl... no
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
            --with-opt-dir
            --without-opt-dir
            --with-opt-include
            --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
            --with-opt-lib
            --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
            --with-make-prog
            --without-make-prog
            --srcdir=.
            --curdir
            --ruby=C:/Ruby/bin/ruby
            --with-curl-dir
            --without-curl-dir
            --with-curl-include
            --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
            --with-curl-lib
            --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
            --with-curllib
            --without-curllib
    extconf.rb:12:   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

      Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
      options to extconf.


    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taf2-curb-0.5.
    4.0 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/taf2-curb-0.5.4.0/ext/gem_make.
    out
```

Next I tried gem install curb. I found this on [PaulDix FeedZirra](http://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) page where he had suggested us that [Todd Fisher](http://github.com/taf2) is working on Ruby binding of libcurl which is called [curb](http://github.com/taf2/curb)

Now, I am getting this error

```
C:\Ruby>gem install curb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing curb:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
"-g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256  $(cflags)"
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include
        --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib
        --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/lib
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
extconf.rb:19:   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/curb-0.7.8 for
 inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/curb-0.7.8/ext/gem_make.out
```

When the error said its because it cant find libcurl or curl/curl.h then I did some googling about it and I found link to [Download Wizard](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html). The best option for a rails newbie is to go with [curl executable](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin) (as suggested ascross various forums and articles) I did that. Extracted the file. Installed the exe file. Now I thought the libcurl problem is solved. But??

Ok, now inorder to install feedzirra, i need to install libxml too. So with a little bit of googling i ended up here at [Libxml ruby forge](http://libxml.rubyforge.org/), downloaded the libxml-ruby-1.1.3 gem and placed it in C:\Ruby\bin folder.

Now, thinking that all set, I am ready to go to learn feed parsing, i enter gem install pauldix-feedzirra. I get the same error "Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h" and the same old list what i got earlier.

For the past 3 days, I am just trying to install this. No luck!

Could someone help me fix this? Basic steps. Please think I dont know how to operate windows. Please go to that basic level when you talk problem fixing terminology and help me to fix this problem.

Looking forward for your help and support in a big way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error installing FeedZirra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919145/error-installing-feedzirra)

Comment: Hi, I dont think its a duplicate question as this is on Windows XP, Ruby 1.8.7 Also the answer that they have provided is curb which I did try to istall here but failed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Curb Installed**

Follow instrictions of [rubyinstaller](http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) and [sakaiproject](http://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/KERNDOC/How+to+install+curl,+ruby,+and+the+rubygem+libraries+%28curb+and+json%29+onto+a+windows+xp+machine)

You would be able to install curb in no time!

Answer (score 0):

yes, curb she will be install in no time. but not taf2-curb. and taf2-curb - this one need for feedzirra. Look on my fighting with taf2-curb, it wouldnt compile in windows for reason.
BTW, i switched to feedtosis, had some active support issues with feedzirra on edge, do not have time to resolve it.